# Alter table and add column but check if the column already exist or not in android studio

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to upgrade the database.
so below method get called.

There are 5 tables. I want to alter only 1table which is last.
But when onupgrade is called last table is not  created yet and cant alter it on Onupgrade method.

```
 @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int currentVersion) {
```

After creating table. I wanted to check if the column exist if not then alter table.I had tried below code but its not working

```
 public static void createuserTable(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {

    final String table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                    + tableName + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user_name TEXT, addressTEXT, phone TEXT, phone2 TEXT)";

     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(table , null); // grab cursor for all data
            int deleteStateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("email");  // see if the column is there
            if (deleteStateColumnIndex < 0) {
                // missing_column not there - add it
                Log.d("value dont exist","value dont exist");
            }
        db.execSQL(table);

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you should know if the column exists or not by following a defined upgrade regime.

However,if the column is readily uniquely identifiable then you could use :-

```
public void createuserTable (SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {

    //Force table to exist (if it doesn't then why not include the email column in the definition? (rhetorical))
    final String table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + tableName + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user_name TEXT, addressTEXT, phone TEXT, phone2 TEXT)";

    String columnName = "email"; //<<<<<<<<<< change as appropriate
    String columnDefinition = " TEXT UNIQUE "; //<<<<<<<<<< change as appropriate
    Cursor cursor;
    if (((
            cursor = db.query(
                    "sqlite_master",
                    new String[]{
                            "sql"
                    },
                    "sql LIKE ? AND type = 'table' AND name = ?", 
                    new String[]{
                            "%" + columnName + "%",
                            tableName
                    }, 
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
                            )).getCount() < 0)){ 
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + tableName +" ADD COLUMN " + columnName + columnDefinition);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

- Of course the column name must not clash with another column name that includes the new column name.

  - e.g. if the new column name were to be col1 and say a column existed name thisiscol1 then as col1 would be found as being part of col1 then the ALTER command would not be executed.
- The above is in-principle code, it has not been tested or run so it may contain some errors.

Comment: It shows this error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:224)

Comment: @iosdeveloper Ooops, had single quotes around the first placeholder (?) so it was taken as a literal rather than a placeholder. Answer updated accordingly.